# Need help replacing text in a sub-element with text from multiple sub-elements in an XML

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to replace the Value text in an XML tree with the text from other sub-elements in the tree. I am new to Python need some help with how to write this.

Example of my XML with some elements omitted for length:

```
<SalesOrder>
  <SalesOrderLines>
    <SalesOrderLine>
      <Item>
        <LineNo>1</LineNo>
        <Quantity>4.00</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <ConfigurationDetails>
         <ConfigurationDetail>
          <ConfigurationAttribute>
            <Name>ConfigurationModel</Name>
            <Value>HV</Value>
          </ConfigurationAttribute>
          <ConfigurationAttribute>
            <Name>EXWidth</Name>
            <Value>59.5</Value>
          </ConfigurationAttribute>
          <ConfigurationAttribute>
            <Name>EXHeight</Name>
            <Value>59.5</Value>
          </ConfigurationAttribute>
          <ConfigurationAttribute>
            <Name>Handing</Name>
            <Value>XO</Value>
          </ConfigurationAttribute>
          <ConfigurationAttribute>
            <Name>LongDescription</Name>
            <Value>This is a long paragraph of text i want to replace with 
            the above text for the Value sub-element</Value>
          </ConfigurationAttribute>
        </ConfigurationDetail>
      </ConfigurationDetails>
    </SalesOrderLine>
  </SalesOrderLines>
</SalesOrder>
```

Here is my first attempt Python code using the `ElementTree` library:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename

Tk().withdraw()
file = askopenfilename()

tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

def model():
    for ConfigurationAttribute in root.iter('ConfigurationAttribute'):
        descrip = ConfigurationAttribute.find('Name').text
        model = ''

        if descrip == 'ConfigurationModel':
            model = ConfigurationAttribute.find('Value').text

def handing():
    for ConfigurationAttribute in root.iter('ConfigurationAttribute'):
        descrip = ConfigurationAttribute.find('Name').text
        handing = ''

        if descrip == 'Handing' and ConfigurationAttribute.find('Value') is 
not None:
            handing = ConfigurationAttribute.find('Value').text

def width():
    for ConfigurationAttribute in root.iter('ConfigurationAttribute'):
        descrip = ConfigurationAttribute.find('Name').text
        width = ''

        if descrip == 'EXWidth':
            width = ConfigurationAttribute.find('Value').text

def height():
    for ConfigurationAttribute in root.iter('ConfigurationAttribute'):
        descrip = ConfigurationAttribute.find('Name').text
        height = ''

         if descrip == 'EXHeight':
            height = ConfigurationAttribute.find('Value').text

for ConfigurationAttribute in root.iter('ConfigurationAttribute'):
    descrip = ConfigurationAttribute.find('Name').text

    if descrip == 'LongDescription':
        model()
        handing()
        width()
        height()        
        ConfigurationAttribute.find('Value').text = str(model), str(handing), 
            str(width), '" x ', str(height), '"' 

tree.write(asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.xml',))
```

This outputs errors. What I am looking is the paragraph of text in the Value sub-element to be replaced with the Value sub-element text from the ConfigurationModel, Handing, EXWidth, and EXHeight Name sub-elements like so:

```
<ConfigurationAttribute>
    <Name>LongDescription</Name>
    <Value> HV, XO, 59.5" x 59.5"</Value>
</ConfigurationAttribute>
```

Below is the error I receive when running the code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\app\users\Home\natep\Documents\NP\py\PrestoParse.py", line 59, in 
    tree.write(asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.xml',))
  File "C:\Users\natep.RANDK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 777, in write
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  File "C:\Users\natep.RANDK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 942, in _serialize_xml
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  File "C:\Users\natep.RANDK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 942, in _serialize_xml
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  File "C:\Users\natep.RANDK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 942, in _serialize_xml
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
  File "C:\Users\natep.RANDK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 939, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(text))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple

In the output file the Value sub-element I'm attempting to change is empty with no closing tag and everything past this is now deleted.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exact error(s) are you seeing? (Usually if your question involves an error, it's a good idea to include the error in your question.)

Comment: Can you use non built-in libraries like `lxml`? Also, there is a misspelling in XML (*SalesOderLine*) and a node that does not close (*ConfigurationDetail*).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I have included the error as well as edited the misspelling in the XML and added to closing tag for ConfigurationDetail. i could use `lxml` if that is the better solution for what I am trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files. Python's third-party module, `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts (not the built-in `etree`) and do so without a single loop.

Specifically, the XSLT script runs the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to copy entire document as is. Then, script adjusts the last *Value* node by extracting preceding siblings with conditional XPath (sibling to XSLT) expressions and finally concatenating text values together with comma separators and needed quotes.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file to be loaded in Python below)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ConfigurationAttribute[Name='LongDescription']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/>
            <Value>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(preceding-sibling::ConfigurationAttribute[Name='ConfigurationModel']/Value, ', ',
                                             preceding-sibling::ConfigurationAttribute[Name='Handing']/Value, ', ',
                                             preceding-sibling::ConfigurationAttribute[Name='EXWidth']/Value, '&quot;', ' X ',
                                             preceding-sibling::ConfigurationAttribute[Name='EXHeight']/Value, '&quot;')"/>
            </Value>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Fiddle Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Cu/1)

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = et.parse('/path/to/Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('/path/to/XSLT_Script.xsl')

# CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    

# RUN TRANSFORMATION
result = transform(doc)

# PRINT RESULT
print(result)  

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('output.xml', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(result)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Great! Glad to help.